# Motorola G2 - "erasing screen" and reboot (over and over)

Tags: factory-reset, boot-loop, motorola-moto-g

I powered up my Moto G v2 and I received a notification about a system update, which I have accepted.

During the update process, came the Android logo with the message "error".

After a manual reboot, came the Android logo with the message "no command".

After some research on the Internet, I discovered that you can hold the Power Button, and then push the Volume UP button, and then a screen will appear to you, giving the options like "reboot the cellphone", "reboot to bootloader", "wipe cache/reset factory", and so on. So, I decided to use the last option. The screen has changed to an Android robot with a gear on the front and on the back, and suddenly, the phone has rebooted to the Motorola welcome screen, going to the same screen with the Android, the gears, and so on.

My questions are:
1 - What's going on exactly / why is this happening ?
2 - How can I fix this / what should I do ?
3 - With this current state, I believe that it is not possible to perform any interaction with Android utilities like "adb" and "flashboot", right?

Answer (score 0):

While running the screen "erasing", press the "Volume Down" button, and after the reboot occasioned by the "loop", the Bootloader screen will appear, and then you can select the "Recovery" mode as usual, giving you  the normal menu screen (wipe cache, factory reset, mount /sys, update from SD card, update from ADB, and so on). With the last option, I was able to manually update the Android, using "adb" commands via terminal + using a update package (for example: http://androidhost.org/plvIU).